# Searching through a text file

Tags: powershell, text-files

I have a script that searches for the lastest modified log file. It then is suppose to read that text file and pick up a key phrase then display the line after it.

So far i have this

```
$logfile = get-childitem 'C:\logs' | sort {$_.lastwritetime} | where {$_ -notmatch "X|Zr" }| select -last 1
$error = get-content $logfile | select-string -pattern "Failed to Modify"
```

an example line it reads is this

> 20150721 12:46:26 398fbb92  To CV Failed to Modify
>   CN=ROLE-x-USERS,OU=Role Groups,OU=Groups,DC=gyp,DC=gypuy,DC=net
>   MDS_E_BAD_MEMBERSHIP One or more members do not exist in the directory

They key bit of information im trying to get here is

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: So what's the problem? It returned the line containing "Failed To Modify", didn't it?

Comment: It just returns the number "1" for some odd reason.

Comment: I take it your quoted output is what you *desire* but not what you're actually getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$error = get-content $logfile | 
    Where-Object { $_ -like "*Failed to Modify*" } | 
    Select-Object -First 1
```

This is provided you are looking for the first match in the file.  The `Select-String` cmdlet returns a `MatchInfo` object.  Depending on your requirements there might be no reason to add that level of complexity if you're just looking to pull the first occurrence of this error in the file.

Failing this, my recommendation would be to debug this and step through it.  Break on the `Get-Content` call and see what `$logfile` is.  Run `Get-Content $logfile` and see what that content looks like.  Then do your `Select-String` on that output.  See what `MatchInfo.ToString()` looks like.  Maybe you'll see some disconnect.

Again, my recommendation would be to just parse manually through the file and work with the `Where-Object` cmdlet at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This shoul work:

```
get-childitem 'c:\logs' | where {$_.Name -notmatch "X|Zr" } | sort {$_.lastwritetime}  | select -last 1 | select-string "Failed to Modify"
```

But I don't like "X|Zr" part. If your log files have .txt extension, it'll not list them because you're saying you don't want any file containing "x" or "zr" in entire name. Use `$_.BaseName` (name without extension), or modify regular expression.

Comment: Again, this just returns "1" very odd.